# Pass route parameter to page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom

I have a menu and I'm trying to pass an ID to a component and the ID just isn't getting to the details page. I've looked at a few examples and still nothing. What am I missing?

menu with link

```
<ul>
   { cars.map((data) => {
       <li key={data.CarId}>
          <Link to=`Cars/Sales/details/${data.CarSalesId}'>Details</Link>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

and on my details page which is located at: src/Cars/Sales/details.js :

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const CarDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();


    //logic here
    console.log(id)   // I get undefined in the console log
 
}
```

What am I missing? I want to show the details page for the selected model

Comment: Can you show the `<Route />` component that's matching to your `<CarDetails />` component? probably an issue there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I have this <CarDetails path="Cars/Sales/:id />. I'm fairly new in using React, so I'm not 100 % sure I follow

Comment: You should have a `Route` with that `path` prop rendered into a `Router` somewhere in your app. Something like `<Route path="Cars/Sales/:id" component={CarDetails} />`. Can you also clarify which version of `react-router-dom` you are using?

Comment: Oh, I gotcha, yeah, it looks like this <Route path='/Cars/Sales/details' component={details}></Route>

Comment: Right, then it should be `<Route path='/Cars/Sales/details/:id' component={Details} />`.

Comment: Adding that to my <Route> worked, thanks. I'm using 6, I created the app a few weeks ago and downloaded the latest (or I think the latest) version

Comment: Are you sure you're in v6? The API changed and there are no longer `render` or `component` props for the `Route` components, it's just a single `element` prop now. Either way, glad to assist. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Do you have an example of that and how can I check the version of everything I'm using? I'd like to stay current if possible.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route and for the version you can check your package.json file or check via npm (I don't know the exact CLI command for this off the top of my head).

Comment: react-dom: "^17.0.2" and react-router-dom: "^5.3.0". I'll have to update it

Comment: Read through the docs (!!) there are lots of fundamental breaking changes if you're used to v3/4/5. Have fun, I think it's a great release. 